# Application of extended euclidean algorithm to find the inverse of polynomial

Tags: ring-theory

I'm trying to understand the Example. ( A quotient ring which is a field) on this page:http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/quotient-rings-of-polynomial-rings/quotient-rings-of-polynomial-rings.html

"
Consider $\dfrac{Q[x]}{\langle x^2 + 2x + 2\rangle}$ . $x^2 + 2x + 2$ is irreducible in $Q[x]$ . Hence, $\dfrac{Q[x]}{\langle x^2 + 2x + 2\rangle}$ is a field.

Now if this is really true, I ought to be able to take a nonzero element and find a multiplicative inverse. For example, I'll find the inverse of $(x^3 + 1) + \langle x^2 + 2x + 2 \rangle$ ."

Specifically, how does he get

$$\dfrac{13}{4} = \left(\dfrac{x^2}{2} - \dfrac{5x}{4} + \dfrac{3}{2}\right) (x^2 + 2x + 2) - \left(\dfrac{x}{2} - \dfrac{1}{4}\right)(x^3 + 1).(*)$$

I factored everything as:
$$x^3+1=(x^2+2x+2)(x-2) +(2x+5) $$
$$x^2+2x+2=(2x+5)(x/2-1/4)+1/4$$
$$2x+5=13/4*(8x/13+20/13)$$

but can't get the algebra to work to get $(*)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \text{ I think that one line should be } \\ x^2+2x+2=(2x+5)(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4})+\frac{13}{4} \\ \text{ subtracting } (2x+5)(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4} )\text{ on both sides gives }\\ (x^2+2x+2)-(2x+5)(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4})=\frac{13}{4} \\ \text{ now replace } 2x+5 \text{ with } (x^3+1)-(x^2+2x+2)(x-2) \\ \text{ so we should have } \\ (x^2+2x+2)-[(x^3+1)-(x^2+2x+2)(x-2)](\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4})=\frac{13}{4} \\ \text{ gathering } (x^3+1) \text{ and the } (x^2+2x+2) \text{ we should have } \\ -(x^3+1)(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4})+(x^2+2x+2)[1+(x-2)(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4})] =\frac{13}{4}$

Comment: perfect thank you. I had 1/4 instead of 13/4.